# Python Argparse Reuse Attributes TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string

Tags: python, argparse

Using argparse in Python 2.7 I am trying to lessen my code by not repeating code and using code for reuse. In this instance, I am trying to reuse arguments given to different subparsers. However, I am getting a error which I thing may be from the way I am trying to call/assign the attributes:

```
import argparse

def create_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Transfer file between accounts.'
                                                  'Add/remove tabs and Schemas')
    subparser = parser.add_subparsers(help='Transfer file between acconts')
    transfer = subparser.add_parser('transfer', 
                                     help="Transfer file from 2 accounts")

    add_arguments(transfer, "producer", "consumer",  "uuid")

    return parser


def add_arguments(group, *args):
    options = group.add_argument_group("Switches")

    choices = {  
            "producer" : ('-p',
                          '--producer',
                          'required=True',
                          'help="Producer\'s(source account)"'),
             "consumer" : ('-c',
                           '--consumer',
                           'required=True',
                           'help="Consumer\'s(destination account)"'),
                 "uuid" : ('-u', 
                           '--uuid',
                           'required=True',
                           'help="file ID number"')}
    for arg in args:
        options.add_argument(choices[arg])
```

---

```
   one@dash ~/image_transfer $ python transfer.py transfer
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "transfer.py", line 19, in <module>
        start()
      File "transfer.py", line 12, in start
        args = vars(parser.parse_args())
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1688, in parse_args
        args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1720, in parse_known_args
        namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1929, in _parse_known_args
        stop_index = consume_positionals(start_index)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1885, in consume_positionals
        take_action(action, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1794, in take_action
        action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1090, in __call__
        namespace, arg_strings = parser.parse_known_args(arg_strings, namespace)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1706, in parse_known_args
        if not hasattr(namespace, action.dest):
    TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string
```

---

```
def start():

    parser = create_args()
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

Comment: The error means that the `action.dest` is the whole tuple `('-p'...')`, when it should just be a string, e.g. `producer`.  Print the `Action` object returned by `options.add_argument(choices[arg])` to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at this:

```
choices = {..
        "producer" : (
            ('-p', '--producer'),
            {'required':True, 'help': "Producer\'s(source account)"}
        ),
        "consumer" : (
            ('-c', '--consumer'),
            {'required':True, 'help': "Consumer\'s(destination account)"}
        ),
        "uuid" : (
            ('-u', '--uuid'),
            {'required':True, 'help': "file ID number"}
        )
}
for arg in args:
    options.add_argument(*choices[arg][0], **choices[arg][1])
```

`add_argument`'s method signature looks like this:

```
add_argument(name or flags...[, action][, nargs][, const][, default][, type][, choices][, required][, help][, metavar][, dest])
```

The name or flags portion are received as `*args` so everything else must be named.  You pass named args from a dictionary by expanding them with `**kwargs`.  In your case you were passing a tuple and it was trying to use it (since it is a single argument) as a `name or flag` and erroring on that.